# Parent Child Grand Child Hierarchy retrieval

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, hana

I want some help in retrieving the parent child grand child etc

This is how my data looks like

```
NODE PARENTNODE ID
----------------------
2    1          DEF
3    2          ABC1
4    2          ABC2
5    4          ABCC3
6    5          XYZ3
22   11         DEF
23   22         DEF1
24   23         DEF2
25   23         DEF3
26   23         DEF4
27   22         DEF5
28   27         DEF6
```

Every time my Parent -ID = DEF ..So for my above data - I have 2 parents

```
NODE PARENTNODE   ID
------------------------
 2    1           DEF
22   11           DEF
```

So when the user is looking for Parent ID = DEF and Parent Node = 1, my result should be

```
NODE PARENTNODE ID
-------------------------
2    1          DEF
3    2          ABC1
4    2          ABC2
5    4          ABCC3
6    5          XYZ3
```

So when the user is looking for Parent ID = DEF and Parent Node = 11, my result should be

```
NODE PARENTNODE   ID
----------------------
22   11           DEF
23   22           DEF1
24   23           DEF2
25   23           DEF3
26   23           DEF4
27   22           DEF5
28   27           DEF6
```

So the idea is the child node becomes the parent node and it can be up to 5 levels.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? for databases that supports it, a recursive cte is the easiest way to handle parent-child tables.

Comment: You should probably check out the Recursive-CTE tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-cte

Answer (score 0):

Use should use some extra columns like lineage, depth to store level and parent info. You can follow [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql) article to get an about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (NODE INT, PARENTNODE INT, ID VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES

(2    ,1  ,'DEF'),
(3    ,2  ,'ABC1'),
(4    ,2  ,'ABC2'),
(5    ,4  ,'ABCC3'),
(6    ,5  ,'XYZ3'),
(22   ,11 ,'DEF'),
(23   ,22 ,'DEF1'),
(24   ,23 ,'DEF2'),
(25   ,23 ,'DEF3'),
(26   ,23 ,'DEF4'),
(27   ,22 ,'DEF5'),
(28   ,27 ,'DEF6')


;WITH CTE AS (
    select NODE , PARENTNODE , ID  from @Temp WHERE ID ='DEF' AND PARENTNODE = 11
    union all
    select T.NODE , T.PARENTNODE , T.ID  from @Temp T INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.NODE = T.PARENTNODE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY NODE
```

Result for Parent Node = 1:

```
NODE        PARENTNODE  ID
----------- ----------- ----------
2           1           DEF
3           2           ABC1
4           2           ABC2
5           4           ABCC3
6           5           XYZ3
```

Result for Parent Node = 11:

```
NODE        PARENTNODE  ID
----------- ----------- ----------
22          11          DEF
23          22          DEF1
24          23          DEF2
25          23          DEF3
26          23          DEF4
27          22          DEF5
28          27          DEF6
```

Comment: Hi -I'm using HANA SQL Editior and it doesn't recognize CTE  in the second SQL Query..Any alternate suggestions..Is there a way to do the same with sub select

Comment: It is a cte pattern for this kind of recursive operations, it can not be made with sub query. But for alternative, i can only recommend to using "while".

Comment: How would you do with the while..Any leads

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you are using Oracle, you may want to look into [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

START WITH specifies the root row(s) of the hierarchy.

CONNECT BY specifies the relationship between parent rows and child rows of the hierarchy.

Sounds like exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SAP HANA database engine does not support [SQL Recursive CTE queries](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) right now.

If you are running HANA 2.0 then you can use the Hierarchy function for querying parent child relations on your database. Please check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jUzCtxTnkA for a tutorial